# Gradle - unable to set distributionUrl that requires credentials

Tags: gradle, artifactory

I am trying to setup Gradle with my Artifactory as the distributionUrl.
When I run gradlew I receive the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: ..
```

I tried to add username:password@ to the URL but it did not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show your build script that you have currently?
Are you trying to pull dependencies from your artifactory repo or publish your artifacts to your repo?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69401685/17373

Answer (score -1):

Use the `username` and `password` properties of the `repository` closure as explained in [the documentation](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Gradle+1.6+Publishing+Artifactory+Plugin).